# useContext with no context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I have defined a context using createContext that wraps some of my components like

```
import MyContext from './mycontext.js'
import A from 'a.js';
import B from b.js';
<MyContext>
    <A/>
    <B/>
</MyContext>
```

where A is defined something like

```
import C from './c.js'
const A = () => {
    return (<C/>);
}
```

And C is define something like

```
import MyContext from 'mycontext.js';

const C = () => {
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(MyContext);
    return (<div>`This is the value - ${!!value ? value : 'UNK'}`</div>)
}
```

Finally the context is created like

const MyContext = createContext({value: '', setValue: () => {}});

The problem is that I get a runtime error

```
TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

From the component C.

I want to make provision for calling C outside of the provider. Not as a wrapped child of the provider. Where does this error come from and how do I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

From only what I can tell from the code snippets it appears you're not rendering any context provider and not providing a context value.

Instead of trying to use the `MyContext` context as a React component, render the `Provider` component.

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{ value: 42, setValue: console.log }}>
  <A />
  <B />
</MyContext.Provider>
```

[image: Edit usecontext-with-no-context]

[image]

Comment: In the original question I have the line
const MyContext = createContext({value: '', setValue: () => {}});

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I saw that and that was also copy/pasted into the codesandbox link in my answer. This is the default value. The `defaultValue` argument is **only** used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext You still need to render a Provider component ***and*** provide a context value.

Comment: What if I wand to use for example component 'C' not as a child of the provider (in other orders just <C/>)? Component 'C' still calls useContext.  It seems the return values in that case are undefined?

Comment: @Kevin Are you asking about rendering component `C` *outside* of a provider's subtree? Yes, `C` will still use, or try to, the context, but in this case it will use the `defaultValue` you passed to `createContext`, i.e. `{ value: '', setValue: () => {} }` from `createContext({value: '', setValue: () => {}});`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to use the default value. I sets it to undefined.

Comment: @Kevin *What* is setting *what* to undefined? Can you be more precise? Just render a context consumer within the ReactTree created by a context provider and you should be able to access the context value (*so long as you are actually providing a **value***).

Comment: The return from useContext is undefined when the component is not a child of the provider.

Comment: @Kevin I see the defined `defaultValue` returned from the context when used outside the provider. See this codesandbox [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-with-no-context-forked-9hvgw?file=/src/App.js). If the context value was truly undefined then attempting to destructure from it would throw an exception. That being said, why are you so concerned with what a context returns when used improperly?